# Excel 2010 VBA - Search text in three columns, then copy information to the right of the column

Tags: excel, vba

I am on my third day of using VBA.  Good so far, but my current problem is a head scratcher.

I have a main sheet (sheet A) that has three drop down (Job Title, Area, Department).  Once a user makes a selection in the drop downs, my second sheet (Sheet B) needs to input data contained in my third sheet (Sheet C).

Sheet C looks as follows:

(Unable to paste image)

i want the three drop downs from Sheet A to search through columns B, C and D(Job Title, Area,  Department).  Once the proper row is identified, I want the information from "Programs" (Programs are listed horizontally beside the job) in columns  F, G, H,... to horizontally populate in Sheet B.

To me, this seems quite challenging.  But hopefully a VBA guru will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

And the code is

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("B:D").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ComboBox2.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("B:D").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ComboBox3.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    If rowNumber = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Record with those details."
    Else
        rowNumber = .Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & rowNumber & ":H" & rowNumber).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

---

Hope this will help you.